# Самостоятельное Изучение Python

Tags: python, книги

Доброго времени суток, недавно начал изучать Python по книге Марка Лутца "Изучаем Питон", пока дошел до 6 главы, возможно, я не прав, но продолжать уже не хочется, т.к. очень много воды и тех вещей по программированию и по ООП, с которыми я знаком по опыту работы на C#, с последним я очень хорошо подружился благодаря книге Культина "C# в задачах и примерах", Культин нас встречает программой перевода фунтов в килограммы с первой же главы, то бишь, он пишет код и объясняет, что куда и зачем на готовом и рабочем коде, чего не скажешь о Лутце. Поэтому мой вопрос в следующем: Есть ли книги по изучению Python, аналогичные книге Культина по изучению C# на примерах? Заранее благодарю.

Comment: Насколько знаю, "изучаем" - это как раз про основы, сам не читал, но чувство такое, что, пропустив что-то, упустите что-то важное. Тот же ООП в python`е немного отличается, например, от php`шного.

Сам только начал читать "Программирование на Python" того же Лутца. Те же "задачи и примеры" в действии.

Два тома по 900 страниц - думаю хватит )

Comment: Да, пожалуй Лутц зануден. Попробуйте Дэвид Бизли, "Python. Подробный справочник". 

(всего (?) 800 стр.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

На самом деле ни какая книга Вам не нужна вовсе. Раз Вы уже знакомы с ООП программированием в целом, то все, что Вас интересует, - это уточнить разницу синтаксиса и выборочно почитать [Python standard library documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/). Собственно по синтаксису вопросы отпадут в процессе чтения, т.к. примеров масса. Этого будет достаточно, чтобы начать писать код на python. Следующий шаг (параллельный) [PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) . А потом открываете документацию по любой(му) библиотеке/фреймворке и спокойно реализуете свои задачи.

Answer (score 0):

[Тут](http://www.learnpython.org/en/Welcome) посмотрите основные фишки и синтаксис и вперед в бой

Answer (score 0):

После C# поведение в ООП python, в некоторых случаях, будет не очень очевидным.

Тут советуют изучать синтаксис и "standart library" документацию, но, по моему мнению, в первую очередь нужно знать все нюансы языка.

Очень хорошо эти нюансы рассказывает Екатерина Тузова в бесплатном курсе от лекториума. Достаточно посмотреть первые 5-6 лекций и многое станет понятным. Думаю, после просмотра этого курса - ваши знания покроют многие задачи.

Но все же почитать Лутца очень полезно.